# Why I don't see any more the TextField inside OnGUI in EditorWindow script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class SearchableWindow : EditorWindow
{
    string searchString = "";

    [MenuItem("Tools/Searching")]
    private static void Searching()
    {
        const int width = 340;
        const int height = 420;

        var x = (Screen.currentResolution.width - width) / 2;
        var y = (Screen.currentResolution.height - height) / 2;

        GetWindow<SearchableWindow>().position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
    }


    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal(EditorStyles.toolbar);
        GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
        searchString = GUILayout.TextField(searchString, EditorStyles.toolbarTextField);
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        var items = Selection.gameObjects;
        // Do comparison here. For example
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            if (items[i].name.Contains(searchString))
            {
                GUILayout.Label(items[i].name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Before it was working fine but now everything is very slow and also I don't see the TextField and when selecting a GameObject in the Hierarchy it's taking almost 5 seconds to show it in the Editor Window.

And before it was all fast and showing the whole Hierarchy in the Editor Window.

Now it's empty:

[image: Searchable window]

I took the answer from this question:

[Searchable](https://answers.unity.com/questions/254396/searchableeditorwindow.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnGUI` is only called while the mouse is (moved/clicked) over the according Window -> it is not taking `almost 5 seconds` but until you move your mouse over the window again.

In order to solve that you could implement [`EditorWindow.OnSelectionChange`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.OnSelectionChange.html) and force a [`EditorWindow.Repaint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.Repaint.html) so your window is refreshed everytime the `Selection` changes.

```
private void OnSelectionChange()
{
    Repaint();
}
```

---

The second issue is produced as follows:

`GUILayout.TextField` together with `GUILayout.FlexibleSpace` if not defined different uses automatically the width of the inserted text -> Since you have an empty text at start the width is *almost* 0 ... you actually can see your TextField very thin there and it gets bigger as you fill it:

[image]

Using the drawers from the `EditorGUILayout` instead solves this:

```
EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal(EditorStyles.toolbar);
GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
searchString = EditorGUILayout.TextField(searchString, EditorStyles.toolbarTextField);
EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

var items = Selection.gameObjects;
// Do comparison here. For example
foreach (var selectedObject in selected)
{
    if (selectedObject .name.Contains(searchString))
    {
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField(selectedObject.name);
    }
}
```

**Tip** If you replace

```
EditorGUILayout.LabelField(items[i].name);
```

with

```
if (GUILayout.Button(selectedObject.name, EditorStyles.label))
{
    EditorGUIUtility.PingObject(selectedObject);
}
```

you can click on the name and "ping" the according GameObject in the hierachy!

---

**Update** since asked in the comments

If you want to include all children of the selection recursive you could do something like (there might be better ways but that's what I came up with within 10 minutes)

```
private static IEnumerable<GameObject> GetChildrenRecursive(GameObject root)
{
    var output = new List<GameObject>();

    //add the root object itself
    output.Add(root);

    // iterate over direct children
    foreach (Transform child in root.transform)
    {
        // add the child itslef
        output.Add(child.gameObject);

        // Recursion here: Get all subchilds of this child
        var childsOfchild = GetChildrenRecursive(child.gameObject);
        output.AddRange(childsOfchild);
    }

    return output;
}

private static IEnumerable<GameObject> GetChildrenRecursive(IEnumerable<GameObject> rootObjects)
{
    var output = new List<GameObject>();


    foreach (var root in rootObjects)
    {
        output.AddRange(GetChildrenRecursive(root));
    }

    // remove duplicates
    return output.Distinct().ToList();
}
```

and using

```
var selected = GetChildrenRecursive(Selection.gameObjects);
```

**Another Update**

Since this might not be very efficient you probably should move it to `Searching` and than only refresh the `selected` value also in `OnSelectionChange` like

```
public class SearchableWindow : EditorWindow
{
    private string searchString = "";
    private List<GameObject> selected;

    [MenuItem("Tools/Searching")]
    private static void Searching()
    {
        const int width = 340;
        const int height = 420;

        var x = (Screen.currentResolution.width - width) / 2;
        var y = (Screen.currentResolution.height - height) / 2;

        var window = GetWindow<SearchableWindow>();
        window.position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);

        window.selected = GetChildrenRecursive(Selection.gameObjects).ToList();
    }

    private void OnSelectionChange()
    {
        selected = GetChildrenRecursive(Selection.gameObjects).ToList();
        Repaint();
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal(EditorStyles.toolbar);
        GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
        searchString = EditorGUILayout.TextField(searchString, EditorStyles.toolbarTextField);
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        // only as fallback
        if (selected == null)
        {
            selected = GetChildrenRecursive(Selection.gameObjects).ToList();
        }

        // Do comparison here. For example
        foreach (var selectedObject in selected)
        {
            if (selectedObject.name.Contains(searchString))
            {
                if (GUILayout.Button(selectedObject.name, EditorStyles.label))
                {
                    EditorGUIUtility.PingObject(selectedObject);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<GameObject> GetChildrenRecursive(GameObject root)
    {
        var output = new List<GameObject>();

        //add the root object itself
        output.Add(root);

        // iterate over direct children
        foreach (Transform child in root.transform)
        {
            // add the children themselves
            output.Add(child.gameObject);

            var childsOfchild = GetChildrenRecursive(child.gameObject);
            output.AddRange(childsOfchild);
        }



        return output;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<GameObject> GetChildrenRecursive(IEnumerable<GameObject> rootObjects)
    {
        var output = new List<GameObject>();

        foreach (var root in rootObjects)
        {
            output.AddRange(GetChildrenRecursive(root));
        }

        // remove any duplicates that would e.g. appear if you select a parent and its child
        return output.Distinct();
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Working great. Small sub question: How can I show a filtered object children too ? For example if I selected all the objects in the Hierarchy and searched for Cube and if the Cube have children show the children too ? Like in the Hierarchy.

Comment: see my Update .. there might be better ways to get all children of the selected objects but this does it

Comment: It's working a bit slowly now when dragging the window. Thanks.

Comment: @DubiDuboni I made another little Update .. maybe you could get it a bit faster if not doing this recursive serach all the time but only when selection is changed or the window opened the first time

Comment: It seems that the slow down happens in the comparison part. It's doing the foreach loop all the time: foreach (var selectedObject in selected)

Comment: Try the last script again. You should use actually a `List<GameObject> selected` instead of an `IEnumerable` and make it a List using `ToList()` as soon as possible to run the enumeration over and over again.